# Should I add spare columns to MySQL table, to prepare for a huge number of rows?

Tags: mysql

One of the issues I've faced with MySQL in the past is dealing with huge tables. Once a table gets over a million rows it becomes more difficult to add columns. There has been a lot of discussion about methods to get around this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44777/how-to-add-column-to-big-table-in-mysql

Planning only goes so far in a business and eventually I know I will need to add more columns. Currently I have about 160,000 so **I am starting to think about future proofing**.

> **Do you think it would be worth me adding spare columns?** In other
>   words, columns that are not used for anything yet.

If so, what approach should I take? Should I add columns for different types like char, int, text, etc?

Comment: Sounds like [premature optimization](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) to me.

Comment: You could consider to move to a more flexible database, one which allows a dynamic schema

Comment: Just create a new table if needed with the additional info, using the pkey from the main table to backreference. It all comes down to reasonable separation of data.

Comment: my plan was to add columns like spare_1, spare_2, spare_3 so that there can be no confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spare columns are not best way in case if new developer have to go through with application so not aware about it or there is a chance that some of the columns are being added in application with no value and you forgot it later.

Some other options could be that suit your needs:

**1**. create new table with one-to-one relationship.

Pros: No issue with existing data and structure. Front-end will be safe if queries are being called using `select *`

Cons: Associated triggers on table will have to be created separately.

**2**. Add more columns to existing table:

Pros: No. of tables will be limited. 
         Table based triggers will not required to be recreated.

Cons: Database structure normalization issue can be raised.
         Column indexing need to be done especially if composite column     indexes. Insert query without column list will broke the system working.

And there is no sense to add column of multiple types without valid prediction.